# Dropping the last segment in a PHP file path

Tags: php

I have a long file path obtained from $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].  Let's say it's

```
 $filePath =  $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];     //     /A/B/C/D/E/F/G/
```

What I want to do now is drop off the last segment, so I have

```
  /A/B/C/D/E/F/
```

But I'm not seeing any clever operators in PHP to do that.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: explode on / rebuild dropping the last one

Comment: Check Php.net for "substr" command

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`dirname`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php) is what you are searching for:

```
var_dump(dirname("/A/B/C/D/E/F/G/")); // string(12) "/A/B/C/D/E/F"
```